# Convert string to IO[str] data type

Tags: python, io, typing, mypy

I have following problem.

For my unit tests purpose, I'm generating the path to the resource file this way:

```py
file_name = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'resources/resource.json'
    )
```

Returned data type of `file_name` var is a `str`.

The method, which I'm testing by this unit test, then accept `IO[str]` data type from [`typing` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Unit test is working, but when I run `mypy` validation on my code, I'm getting following error message:

```
tests/test_get_requirements.py:73: error: Argument 1 to "JiraRequirements" has incompatible type "str"; expected "IO[str]"

Line **73** is basically the instantiation of new object of *JiraRequirements class*

MockedObject = JiraRequirements(file_name)
```

Comment: What is JiraRequirements? What does the `__init__` method say? Can you change it or is it an external library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mypy error is correct. You pass `str` filename where `typing` expects an opened file object. From `IO` docs:

> This is an abstract, generic version of the return of open().

Comment: Ah, you are right, just using open(file_name) in argument for the method fixed the issue. Thanks a lot, that was pretty fast :).

Comment: @chaotic if JiraRequirements works fine with both a filename and an open file then the signature should be changed to reflect that.